# How to update a single cell in a row in react using only Class components. I have no knowledge of hooks or material table

Tags: reactjs

I want to update the bidAmount for one row. However, when I update both the rows are getting changed. I have no knowledge of hooks or material table so kindly explain using react Class components. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Here is my response json.

```
[
{
    "bid": {
        "id": "b101",
        "firstName": "Radek",
        "lastName": "Stepanek",
        "address": "84 street",
        "city": "prague",
        "state": "prague",
        "pin": "678912",
        "phone": "7897896789",
        "email": "radek.stepanek@gmail.com",
        "productId": "watch101",
        "bidAmount": 14000.0
    },
    "product": {
        "id": "watch101",
        "productName": "Rolex sp 1",
        "shortDescription": "Rolex special edition",
        "detailedDescription": "Rolex special edition launched in 1950",
        "category": "Watch",
        "startingPrice": 10000,
        "bidEndDate": "2024-01-23T12:34:56.123+00:00",
        "seller": {
            "id": "seller1",
            "firstName": "Roger",
            "lastName": "Federer",
            "address": "26 street",
            "city": "Basel",
            "state": "Basel",
            "pin": "780123",
            "phone": "9123456789",
            "email": "roger.federer@gmail.com"
        }
    }
},
{
    "bid": {
        "id": "b102",
        "firstName": "Grigor",
        "lastName": "Dimitrov",
        "address": "104 street",
        "city": "sofia",
        "state": "sofia",
        "pin": "578912",
        "phone": "8897896789",
        "email": "grigor.dimitrov@gmail.com",
        "productId": "watch101",
        "bidAmount": 12000.0
    },
    "product": {
        "id": "watch101",
        "productName": "Rolex sp 1",
        "shortDescription": "Rolex special edition",
        "detailedDescription": "Rolex special edition launched in 1950",
        "category": "Watch",
        "startingPrice": 10000,
        "bidEndDate": "2024-01-23T12:34:56.123+00:00",
        "seller": {
            "id": "seller1",
            "firstName": "Roger",
            "lastName": "Federer",
            "address": "26 street",
            "city": "Basel",
            "state": "Basel",
            "pin": "780123",
            "phone": "9123456789",
            "email": "roger.federer@gmail.com"
        }
    }
}
```

]

[image]

I added bidAmount to the state and attached an onChange handler but it is changing bidAmount for all the rows. I want to change bidAmount for only a specific row.

```
    import axios from "axios";
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import ProductDetails from "./ProductDetails";
    import BidDetails from "./BidDetails";

    class GetBidDetails extends Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state = {
                productId: '',
                bidRows: [],
                isInEditMode: false,
                bidAmt: 0
            }
        }

        handleProductIdChange = event => {
            this.setState({
                productId: event.target.value
            })
        }

        handleSubmit = event => {
            event.preventDefault()
            axios.get(`http://localhost:8082/e-auction/api/v1/seller/show-bids/${this.state.productId}`)
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response);
                    this.setState({
                        bidRows: response.data
                    })
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                })
        }

        editBidAmount = (id) => {
            this.setState({
                isInEditMode: !this.state.isInEditMode
            })
            console.log(id);
        }

        handleBidAmountChange = (e, id) => {
            this.setState({
                bidAmt: e.target[id].value
            })
        }
        
        render() {
            var bidJA = [];
            var finalJA = [];
            const { bidRows } = this.state;
            let productExist = bidRows.length > 0 ? true: false;
            if(productExist) {
                bidRows.map(row => bidJA.push(row.bid))
                bidJA.map(row => {
                    
                })
            }
            //console.log('Value of bidJA is '+JSON.stringify(bidJA));
            return(
                <div>
                    <br></br><br></br>
                    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <div>
                            <label id="productIdLabel">Product ID </label>&nbsp;
                            <input type="text" value={this.state.productId} onChange={this.handleProductIdChange}/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <button type="submit">Get All Bids</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <br></br>
                    {
                        bidRows.length ? <ProductDetails {...bidRows[0].product} /> : null
                    }
                    <br></br><br></br>
                    {
                        bidRows.length ? 
                        <table id="tbl">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Bid Amount</th>
                                    <th>Name </th>
                                    <th>Email </th>
                                    <th>Phone </th>
                                </tr>
                                {bidJA.map((row, rowIndex) => (
                                <tr key={rowIndex}>
                                    <td><input type="text" 
                                            value={this.state.isInEditMode? this.state.bidAmt: row.bidAmount}
                                            onChange={() => this.handleBidAmountChange(row.id)}/></td>
                                    <td>{row.firstName} {row.lastName}</td>
                                    <td>{row.email}</td>
                                    <td>{row.phone}</td>
                                    <td><button onClick={this.editBidAmount}>Edit</button>&nbsp;<button>Update</button></td>
                                </tr>
                                ))}
                            </tbody>
                        </table> : null
                        
                    }
                    
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    export default GetBidDetails;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that, you are using the state variable bidAmt in the value field.

Instead of rendering the state value in bidAmt, use the value from row variable itself. And during onChange, just update the amount value for the specific row so that it doesn't change the entire table.

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ProductDetails from "./ProductDetails";
import BidDetails from "./BidDetails";

class GetBidDetails extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      productId: "",
      bidRows: [],
      isInEditMode: false,
      bidAmt: 0,
    };
  }

  handleProductIdChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      productId: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    axios
      .get(
        `http://localhost:8082/e-auction/api/v1/seller/show-bids/${this.state.productId}`
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({
          bidRows: response.data,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  editBidAmount = (id) => {
    this.setState({
      isInEditMode: !this.state.isInEditMode,
    });
    console.log(id);
  };

  handleBidAmountChange = (e, id) => {
    let tmp = [...this.state.bidRows];
    tmp[id]["bid"].bidAmount = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
      bidRows: tmp,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { bidRows } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div>
            <label id="productIdLabel">Product ID </label>&nbsp;
            <input
              type="text"
              value={this.state.productId}
              onChange={this.handleProductIdChange}
            />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button type="submit">Get All Bids</button>
          </div>
        </form>
        <br></br>
        {bidRows.length ? <ProductDetails {...bidRows[0].product} /> : null}
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        {bidRows.length ? (
          <table id="tbl">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>Bid Amount</th>
                <th>Name </th>
                <th>Email </th>
                <th>Phone </th>
              </tr>
              {bidRows.map((row, rowIndex) => (
                <tr key={rowIndex}>
                  <td>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      value={row.bid.bidAmount}
                      onChange={(e) => this.handleBidAmountChange(e, rowIndex)}
                    />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    {row.bid.firstName} {row.bid.lastName}
                  </td>
                  <td>{row.bid.email}</td>
                  <td>{row.bid.phone}</td>
                  <td>
                    <button onClick={this.editBidAmount}>Edit</button>&nbsp;
                    <button>Update</button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default GetBidDetails;
```

Comment: thanks, but it is not working. I'm getting the below error.

Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'bidAmount')

Comment: Is it throwing any error? Can you explain?

Comment: yes, it is throwing error.

Comment: should we make any changes to the setState method in your code?


handleBidAmountChange = (e, id) => {
        let bidRows = [...this.state.bidRows];
        bidRows[id].bidAmount = e.target.value;
        this.setState({
            bidRows
        })
        
    }

Comment: Can you post the error in question

Comment: If you want I can give you the link to my repo.

Comment: I have update the code to use `rowIndex` in the onChange function inside `td`. Can you try that. If it doesn't work, then you can share the repo link

Comment: GetBidDetails.js:53 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'bidAmount')
    at GetBidDetails.handleBidAmountChange (GetBidDetails.js:53:1)
    at onChange (GetBidDetails.js:101:1)

Comment: GetBidDetails.js:53 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'bidAmount')
    at GetBidDetails.handleBidAmountChange (GetBidDetails.js:53:1)
    at onChange (GetBidDetails.js:101:1)

Comment: Now, edit button doesn't work. Please use my git repo.
https://github.com/abhijitnath90/e-auction-ui.git

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253958/discussion-between-abhijit-and-the-marolie).